# why X|Y=y isn't considered to be a random variable

Tags: random-variable

I read about conditioning of random variables and I got a little bit confused.
Why $X|Y=y$ isn't considered to be a random variable (it is just a function of $y$'s) while $E(X|Y=y)$ can be considered as a random variable?
By definition of random variables from wikipedia it seems that also $X|Y=y$ satisfies it, so where is my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$X|Y = y$ is certainly a random variable for a *fixed* $y$. So, for example, $X|Y = 3$ is a random variable. But $X|Y = 4$ is in general a different random variable, and so is $X|Y = 5$, and so on.

$E(X|Y = 3)$ isn't a random variable; it's a fixed value, namely, whatever the mean of $X$ is given that $Y = 3$. $E(X|Y)$, on the other hand, is a random variable because it gives the value $E(X|Y = y)$ for a random value $y$ of $Y$.

Comment: I think the confusion stems from the fact that many texts have the incorrect X|Y notation which is actually not a random variable when Y is not bound to a particular y.